# Exam question: Find the directional derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A question from a previous multivariable-calculus exam says:

Let $D=\mathbb R^2$ and
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}  2xy/(x^2+y^2) & \text{if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$,} \\ 1 & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.} \end{cases}
$$
Find the directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in direction $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

Any hint on how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\underline{v} = ( \cos \alpha, \sin \alpha ) $. Then, the directional derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in the direction of $\underline{v} $ is:

$$ D_{\underline{v} }(0,0) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \frac{f(\epsilon \underline{v} + 0) - f(0)}{\epsilon}$$

Now, you know $f(0) = 1 $ and $$f(\epsilon\cos \alpha , \epsilon \sin \alpha ) = \frac{2 \epsilon^2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha }{\epsilon^2 \cos^2 \alpha + \epsilon^2 \sin \alpha}  $$

This is a hint.

Second hint:

$$ \sin (2 \alpha )  = 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha $$

$$ \sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1 $$